# Issues when querying multiple entities with LINQ and ObjectSet, type conversion errors?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a model comprised of multiple entities. I am trying to write a LINQ statement in my controller to query some of these entities. Thanks in advance for any help offered, this is driving me crazy.

For each ObjectSet statement (see below) I receive the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyApp.Models.MY_ENTITY_1>' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<MyApp.Models.MY_ENTITY_1>'
```

Here is my code:

```
 public class MyController : ApiController
    {
    private MyEntities context = new MyEntities();

    public IQueryable <string> Get()

    {
        ObjectSet<MY_ENTITY_1> my_entity_1 = context.MY_ENTITY_1; //Error here
        ObjectSet<MY_ENTITY_2> my_entity_2 = context.MY_ENTITY_2; //Error here
        ObjectSet<MY_ENTITY_3> my_entity_3 = context.MY_ENTITY_3; //Error here

        var query =
            from MY_ENTITY_1 in my_entity_1
            from MY_ENTITY_2 in my_entity_2
            from MY_ENTITY_3 in my_entity_3

            where
                 MY_ENITITY_1.something == MY_ENTITY_2.something

            select new
                {
                    Result1 = MY_ENTITY_1.FOO1,
                    Result2 = MY_ENTITY_2.FOO2,
                    Result3 = MY_ENTITY_3.FOO3
                };

        foreach (var myResults in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myResults);
        };

        return myResults;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbSet<T>` doesn't inherit from `ObjectSet<T>`

you could change it by

```
IQueryable<MY_ENTITY_1> my_entity_1 = context.MY_ENTITY_1;
IQueryable<MY_ENTITY_2> my_entity_2 = context.MY_ENTITY_2;
IQueryable<MY_ENTITY_3> my_entity_3 = context.MY_ENTITY_3;
```

Or simply remove that intermediate object from that query

```
var query = from MY_ENTITY_1 in context.MY_ENTITY_1
            from MY_ENTITY_2 in context.MY_ENTITY_2
            from MY_ENTITY_3 in context.MY_ENTITY_3
            where MY_ENITITY_1.something == MY_ENTITY_2.something
            select new
            {
                Result1 = MY_ENTITY_1.FOO1,
                Result2 = MY_ENTITY_2.FOO2,
                Result3 = MY_ENTITY_3.FOO3
            };
```

Comment: Does this fix your problem?

Comment: Marking as answer will give you 2 of reputation